# Select only the first row when merging data frames with multiple matches

Tags: r, join

I have two data frames, "data" and "scores", and want to merge them on the "id" column:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  state = c("KS","MN","AL","FL","CA"))
scores = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                    score = c(66,75,78,86,85,76,75,90))
merge(data, scores, by = "id")                  
semi_join(data, scores, by = "id")
```

In the "scores" data, there are "id" with multiple observations, where each match gets a row following the join. See `?merge`:

> If there is more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each.

However, I want keep only the row corresponding to the *first* match from the `scores` table.

A semi join would have been nice, but I'm not able to select the score from the right table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `data.table` along with `mult = "first"` and `nomatch = 0L`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(scores); setDT(data) # convert to data.tables by reference

scores[data, mult = "first", on = "id", nomatch=0L]
#    id score state
# 1:  1    66    KS
# 2:  2    86    MN
# 3:  3    76    AL
```

For each row on `data`'s `id` column, the matching rows in `scores`' `id` column are found, and the first one alone is retained (because `mult = "first"`). If there are no matches, they're removed (because of `nomatch = 0L`).

Comment: How about using a keyed `scores` data.table: `setDT(data);
scores <- data.table(scores, key = "id");
unique(scores)[data, nomatch = 0L]`

Comment: It'd work fine, but is just very inefficient. `data.table()` results in a deep copy. The key argument would reorder the entire data.table (inefficient unless case can be made for reuse and probably undesirable). `unique()` results in unnecessary intermediate data. And `on=` also allows for a clean syntax to just look at it and understand what the join column is (although it can be used on keyed data.tables as well). I recommend reading the [secondary indices](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette.

Comment: Hi @Arun is it possible to tell `mult` to take the highest value according to another column instead of the first ?

Comment: @OrhanYazar not with rolling joins, but possibly with non-equi joins. Post a Q and tag it here maybe? I (or other so many able people here on SO) could take a look.

Comment: The mult = "first" option doesn't work if you change the order of the datatables  data[scores, mult = "first", on = "id", nomatch=0L]

Answer (score 10):

Here is a base R method using `aggregate` and `head`:

```
merge(data, aggregate(score ~ id, data=scores, head, 1), by="id")
```

The `aggregate` function breaks up the scores dataframe by id, then `head` is applied to get the first observation from each id. Since `aggregate` returns a data.frame, this is directly merged onto the data.frame data.

---

Probably more efficient is to subset the scores data.frame using `duplicated` which will achieve the same result as `aggregate`, but will reduce the computational overhead.

```
merge(data, scores[!duplicated(scores$id),], by="id")
```

Comment: This solution is good, but it is inefficient. I would use dplyr::distinct to replace aggregate.

Comment: Thanks @huanfa-chen. Your suggestion gave me the idea to use `duplicated` in place of `aggregate + head` which will certainly be more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another method using dplyr::distinct. It is useful if you want to keep all rows from 'data' even if there is no match.

```
data = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  state=c("KS","MN","AL","FL","CA"))
scores = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                    score=c(66,75,78,86,85,76,75,90))
data %>% dplyr::left_join(dplyr::distinct(scores, id, .keep_all = T))
# Joining, by = "id"
# id state score
# 1  1    KS    66
# 2  2    MN    86
# 3  3    AL    76
# 4  4    FL    NA
# 5  5    CA    NA
```

Moreover, if you want to replace the NAs in the new data.frame, try the tidyr::replace_na() function. Example:

```
data %>% dplyr::left_join(dplyr::distinct(scores, id, .keep_all = T)) %>% tidyr::replace_na(replace = list("score"=0L))
# Joining, by = "id"
# id state score
# 1  1    KS    66
# 2  2    MN    86
# 3  3    AL    76
# 4  4    FL     0
# 5  5    CA     0
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use [match](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/match) to *Select only the first row when merging data frames with multiple matches*.

```
#Return also those which found no match
(tt <- cbind(data, score=scores[match(data$id, scores$id),"score"]))
#  id state score
#1  1    KS    66
#2  2    MN    86
#3  3    AL    76
#4  4    FL    NA
#5  5    CA    NA

#Return only those which found a match
tt[!is.na(tt$score),]
#  id state score
#1  1    KS    66
#2  2    MN    86
#3  3    AL    76
```