# Using dplyr to merge datasets and consolidate columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, subset, consolidation

I have two datasets that I am trying to merge. They are not complete datasets, so this means that individuals are missing records.

Here is `data1` (example is a subset of my real data):

```
  squirrel_id   age ageclass trialdate   year   OFT1  MIS1
        10342     1 Y        2008-05-19  2008  0.605 -4.19
        10342     2 A        2009-05-31  2009 -1.85   1.14
        10342     3 A        2010-05-22  2010 -2.39   2.38
```

Here is `data2` (example is a subset of my real data):

```
   squirrel_id focal_age focal_ageclass focal_date focal_yr     PC1     PC2
         10342         1 Y              2008-07-14     2008    0.0932 -2.67  
         10342         3 A              2010-03-13     2010   -2.38    0.216 
         10342         3 A              2010-04-20     2010    0.0203  1.80
```

I'm trying to do two things:

1. merge these two datasets so that I retain NAs when records are incomplete (i.e., `data1` has 1 record at `age==3`, while `data2` has 2 records when `age==3`)
2. consolidate columns to make the dataset more streamlined (i.e., columns with different names in the datasets represent the same things: `age==focal_age`, `ageclass==focal_ageclass`, `trialnumber==focalseq`, `ageclass==focal_ageclass`,  `year==focal_yr`)

**Desired output -** I am trying to have a final dataset that looks like this (where for `age==3` the `data1` record is only shown once, not twice):

```
  squirrel_id   age ageclass date       year   OFT1  MIS1   PC1      PC2
        10342     1 Y        2008-05-19 2008  0.605 -4.19   NA       NA 
        10342     1 Y        2008-07-14 2008  NA     NA     0.0932  -2.67
        10342     2 A        2009-05-31 2009 -1.85   1.14   NA       NA
        10342     3 A        2010-05-22 2010 -2.39   2.38   NA       NA    
        10342     3 A        2010-03-13 2010  NA     NA    -2.38    0.216
        10342     3 A        2010-04-20 2010  NA     NA     0.0203  1.80
```

I am able to get partway here by doing:

```
data3<-full_join(data1, data2, 
        by=c("squirrel_id"="squirrel_id", 
                    "year"="focal_yr", 
                     "age"="focal_age", 
                "ageclass"="focal_ageclass"))
```

but this repeats the `data1` values for `age==3` for both `age==3` rows in `data2` (instead of just matching the first row only), giving this (**not desired**) output:

```
 squirrel_id   age ageclass trialdate   focal_date year   OFT1  MIS1   PC1      PC2
        10342     1 Y        2008-05-19  2008-07-14 2008  0.605 -4.19   0.0932  -2.67 
        10342     2 A        2009-05-31  NA         2009 -1.85   1.14   NA       NA
        10342     3 A        2010-05-22  2010-03-13 2010 -2.39   2.38   -2.38    0.216
        10342     3 A        2010-05-22  2010-04-20 2010 -2.39   2.38    0.0203  1.80
```

*Updated Question:* **How do I have the matching records add NAs for all rows when doing a `full_join`?** Note that I'd rather a `dplyr` solution, as I don't work in `data.table` (like the answer to [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167918/how-to-join-data-to-only-the-first-matching-row-with-data-table-in-r)) and I want to retain the rows that don't match (unlike [this other OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749412/select-only-the-first-row-when-merging-data-frames-with-multiple-matches)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- fread("squirrel_id   age ageclass trialdate   year   OFT1  MIS1
10342     1 Y        2008-05-19  2008  0.605 -4.19
10342     2 A        2009-05-31  2009 -1.85   1.14
10342     3 A        2010-05-22  2010 -2.39   2.38")

data2 <- fread("squirrel_id focal_age focal_ageclass focal_date focal_yr     PC1     PC2
         10342         1 Y              2008-07-14     2008    0.0932 -2.67  
         10342         3 A              2010-03-13     2010   -2.38    0.216 
         10342         3 A              2010-04-20     2010    0.0203  1.80 ")
```

**code**

```
# Assuming the first five columns can be rowbound without problem,
# melt them to long
L <- lapply(list(data1, data2), melt, id.vars = 1:5)

#    squirrel_id age ageclass  trialdate year variable  value
# 1:       10342   1        Y 2008-05-19 2008     OFT1  0.605
# 2:       10342   2        A 2009-05-31 2009     OFT1 -1.850
# 3:       10342   3        A 2010-05-22 2010     OFT1 -2.390
# 4:       10342   1        Y 2008-05-19 2008     MIS1 -4.190
# 5:       10342   2        A 2009-05-31 2009     MIS1  1.140
# 6:       10342   3        A 2010-05-22 2010     MIS1  2.380
# 
# [[2]]
#    squirrel_id focal_age focal_ageclass focal_date focal_yr variable   value
# 1:       10342         1              Y 2008-07-14     2008      PC1  0.0932
# 2:       10342         3              A 2010-03-13     2010      PC1 -2.3800
# 3:       10342         3              A 2010-04-20     2010      PC1  0.0203
# 4:       10342         1              Y 2008-07-14     2008      PC2 -2.6700
# 5:       10342         3              A 2010-03-13     2010      PC2  0.2160
# 6:       10342         3              A 2010-04-20     2010      PC2  1.8000

# Rowbind, ignore columnnames
DT <- data.table::rbindlist(L, use.names = FALSE, fill = FALSE)
#    squirrel_id age ageclass  trialdate year variable   value
# 1:       10342   1        Y 2008-05-19 2008     OFT1  0.6050
# 2:       10342   2        A 2009-05-31 2009     OFT1 -1.8500
# 3:       10342   3        A 2010-05-22 2010     OFT1 -2.3900
# 4:       10342   1        Y 2008-05-19 2008     MIS1 -4.1900
# 5:       10342   2        A 2009-05-31 2009     MIS1  1.1400
# 6:       10342   3        A 2010-05-22 2010     MIS1  2.3800
# 7:       10342   1        Y 2008-07-14 2008      PC1  0.0932
# 8:       10342   3        A 2010-03-13 2010      PC1 -2.3800
# 9:       10342   3        A 2010-04-20 2010      PC1  0.0203
#10:       10342   1        Y 2008-07-14 2008      PC2 -2.6700
#11:       10342   3        A 2010-03-13 2010      PC2  0.2160
#12:       10342   3        A 2010-04-20 2010      PC2  1.8000

# Cast to wide again
dcast(DT, ... ~ variable, value.var = "value")
#    squirrel_id age ageclass  trialdate year   OFT1  MIS1     PC1    PC2
# 1:       10342   1        Y 2008-05-19 2008  0.605 -4.19      NA     NA
# 2:       10342   1        Y 2008-07-14 2008     NA    NA  0.0932 -2.670
# 3:       10342   2        A 2009-05-31 2009 -1.850  1.14      NA     NA
# 4:       10342   3        A 2010-03-13 2010     NA    NA -2.3800  0.216
# 5:       10342   3        A 2010-04-20 2010     NA    NA  0.0203  1.800
# 6:       10342   3        A 2010-05-22 2010 -2.390  2.38      NA     NA
```

Comment: Any idea why R is throwing me `Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'` as an error after I run the `dcast(DT, ... ~ variable, value.var = "value")` line?

Comment: yes.. That is an indication you have multiple values on some rows, per OFT/MSI/PC!/PC2... ItDThe default to length shows the number of values you have, in stead of the actual values.