# Merging data frames in R without duplicating rows in x due to repeated values in y

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have two data frames EMOJ and EYETRACK and I need to merge them by "session", without duplicating rows.

Dataframes:

```
> EMOJ
  session age attitude
1    s001  18        2
2    s002  22        4


> EYETRACK
  session stimuli response_time
1    s001       A          1023
2    s001       B          1009
3    s001       C          1832
4    s002       A          1092
5    s002       B          1076
```

What I want:

```
  session age attitude stimuli response_time
1    s001  18        2       A          1023
2    s001                    B          1009
3    s001                    C          1832
4    s002  22        4       A          1092
5    s002                    B          1076
```

What I am getting:

```
df <- merge(EMOJ, EYETRACK, by.x = 'session', by.y = 'session')

  session age attitude stimuli response_time
1    s001  18        2       A          1023
2    s001  18        2       B          1009
3    s001  18        2       C          1832
4    s002  22        4       A          1092
5    s002  22        4       B          1076
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749412/select-only-the-first-row-when-merging-data-frames-with-multiple-matches this might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this but I had to add 'stimuli' to the EMOJ df

```
EMOJ$stimuli <- 'A'

df1 <- merge(EMOJ, EYETRACK, by = c('session','stimuli'), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I already tried that and it only copies the first row of EYETRACK that matches EMOJ. In that way, a portion of EYETRACK's data is lost.

Comment: @Olivia I reworked my answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
EMOJ %>%
  left_join(distinct(EYETRACK, session, .keep_all = T)) %>%
  full_join(EYETRACK)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  session age attitude stimuli response_time
1    s001  18        2       A          1023
2    s002  22        4       A          1092
3    s001  NA       NA       B          1009
4    s001  NA       NA       C          1832
5    s002  NA       NA       B          1076
```

EDIT: Following Ruam's recommendation, I included the output. For some reason, my past response didn't give me the same output as the first time I ran it, so I updated the response. Now it should work.

Comment: you may want to add the output as well so people can easily verify your coding.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to number each row within each session consecutively. Then `merge` on both the `session` and this index number. Only the first row within each `session` from both data.frames will be merged. If there's only 1 row per `session` in EMOJ, can simply use `EMOJ$i <- 1`.

```
library(data.table)

EMOJ$i <- rowid(EMOJ$session)
EYETRACK$i <- rowid(EYETRACK$session)

merge(EYETRACK, EMOJ, by = c("session", "i"), all.x = T)
```

**Output**

```
  session i stimuli response_time age attitude
1    s001 1       A          1023  18        2
2    s001 2       B          1009  NA       NA
3    s001 3       C          1832  NA       NA
4    s002 1       A          1092  22        4
5    s002 2       B          1076  NA       NA
```